# nusoap exception Illegal argument invoking

Tags: java, php, laravel-5, nusoap, webservices-client

the project made in laravel, call via SOAP to Web service in java, using nusoap complement

```
$factura=Facturas::find($id);
    $folio=$factura->folio.'L';
    $dataws=[
    'serie'=>$factura->serie,
    'folio'=>intval($folio),
    'rfcRecibido'=>$factura->distribuidor->rfc,
    'key'=>'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx'
    ];
$websc = new nusoap_client('https://portal3.xsa.com.mx/xsamanager/services/CancelCFDService');
    $error = $websc->getError();
```

when call function cancelCFD

```
$result = $websc->call('cancelaCFD', $dataws);
        if ($websc->fault) {
        echo '<h3>Error</h3><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
            echo response()->json(array('success'=>false,'codigo'=>$result));
    }
```

the ws sends this

```
{"faultcode":"soap:Client","faultstring":"Illegal argument invoking 'com.tralix.xsa.manager.cancel.ws.ICancelService.cancelaCFD(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)': java.lang.ClassCastException@40751341"}}
```

**how make the integer value (folio) to long**

Comment: can you try floatval($folio) ?

Comment: yes, same answer of ws